# Null-check manually converted TextField value

Tags: wicket

I have a TextField which overrides it's getConverter method to add a Joda time converter instead:

```java
new TextField<P>(id) {
    @Override
    public <P> IConverter<P> getConverter(Class<P> type) {
        return (IConverter<P>) new JodaDateTimeConverter();
    }
};
```

The converter returns null if input was invalid. However, I want to be able to **flag this field as required**, and I don't know how to do that:

- textField.isRequired(true) does not work, because required checks are done before conversion. This doesn't work for non-empty but invalid inputs.
- textField.add(.. some validator ..) does not work because no validator is called if the converter returned null.

I really don't see an approach to flag my date fields as required. Do you know how to do that? Probably my approach is not suited at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an [INullAcceptingValidator](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.5.x/org/apache/wicket/validation/INullAcceptingValidator.html) instead of a regular one, it will be called for null values too.

Subclassing your validators to return true on `validateOnNullValue()` might be helpfull too.

From the JavaDocs:

> Indicates whether or not to validate the value if it is null. It is
>   usually desirable to skip validation if the value is null, unless we
>   want to make sure the value is in fact null (a rare use case).
>   Validators that extend this and wish to ensure the value is null
>   should override this method and return true.